# How to change rev-list in tig

Tags: git, tig

`tig` provides useful rev-list filtering on the command line.
My questions is - how do I filter the rev-list "after" the `tig` has been invoked.
For example, I'd like to browse different branches with "refs-view".

And then do the rev-list filtering such as --author, --no-merges, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the rev-list filtering arguments in tig. The only thing that can be manipulated is file filtering, which can be toggled on/off.

I suggest you open an issue: https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues